# Want six instances of command prompt window to be running at any point of time unless all the 100 commands are completed

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set maxInstances=6
rem Delete all cmd instance files
del cmdInstance?.txt 2>NUL
for /F "tokens=*" %%x in (C:\Users\phare\Desktop\Batch\Post.txt) do (
   rem Mimic commandline
   echo cmd /K "cd Desktop\Batch" ^> %%x BatchStartTime=%date:~7,2%_%date:~3,3%_%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%> C:\Users\phare\Desktop\Batch\log.txt
   rem Perform command
   call :WaitForNextInstance
   echo This instance started at !time! > cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt 
   Start "" "cmd /C call %%x & del cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt"
   echo/
)
goto :EOF  
:WaitForNextInstance
rem Review active instances and get the first available one
for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxInstances%) do if not exist cmdInstance%%i.txt set "nextInstance=%%i" & exit /B
echo cmd /K "cd Desktop\Batch" ^> 
rem Delay some time (10 seconds in this example) and repeat
ping -n 11 localhost >NUL 
goto WaitForNextInstance
```

Comment: Show a few lines from Curl.txt. Why are you setting CMD inside of the for loop? It's a static variable and can be set outside of the loop. Also you have to use REM inside of a for loop for comments. `::` causes issues.

Comment: Could you use an alternative cmd program? https://www.nextofwindows.com/4-better-windows-console-tools-alternatives-to-windows-built-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is interesting! You need that a monitor program continually review the active cmd.exe processes and start the next one when needed. Of course, this program waste some CPU time, so you must carefully choose a delay in the loop that check if one of the six processes ends: if this delay is very short, the monitor process waste a lot of CPU time; if this delay is very large, it may takes too much time between one of the six processes ends and the next one starts.

You may check the number of active cmd.exe instances via `tasklist` and filter the output, but it is much easier to create a file for each active cmd.exe instance that will be deleted when the instance ends.

**EDIT** Response to the comments: "incremental execution" and start time and end time of the entire execution added.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Delete all cmd instance files
del cmdInstance*.txt 2>NUL

rem Report start time
echo BatchStartTime=%date:~7,2%%date:~3,3%%date:~10,4% @ %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% > C:\Users\phare\Desktop\Batch\log.txt

rem Set starting number of concurrent instances
set maxInstances=1

for /F "tokens=*" %%x in (C:\Users\phare\Desktop\Batch\Post.txt) do (
   rem Mimic commandline
   echo cmd /K "cd Desktop\Batch" ^> %%x
   rem Perform command
   call :WaitForNextInstance
   echo This instance started at !time! > cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt 
   Start "" "cmd /C call %%x & del cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt"
   echo/
)

rem Wait for all active instances end
call :WaitAllInstancesEnd
rem Report end time and terminate
echo BatchEndTime=%date:~7,2%%date:~3,3%%date:~10,4% @ %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% > C:\Users\phare\Desktop\Batch\log.txt
goto :EOF 

:WaitForNextInstance
rem Review active instances and get the first available one
for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxInstances%) do if not exist cmdInstance%%i.txt set "nextInstance=%%i" & exit /B
rem Current maxInstances reached: wait for all previous instances end
call :WaitAllInstancesEnd
rem Increment number of maxInstances and repeat
set /A maxInstances+=1
goto WaitForNextInstance

:WaitAllInstancesEnd
rem Check if any instance is still active
set "anyInstance="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%maxInstances%) do if exist cmdInstance%%i.txt set anyInstance=true
if not defined anyInstance exit /B
rem Delay some time (10 seconds in this example) and repeat
ping -n 11 localhost >NUL
goto WaitAllInstancesEnd
```

Please, post the result...

Comment: Hey Aacini, Thanks for your effort. But the command dosent work. When i ran this command I am getting error for this command Start "" "call %%x ^& del cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt". I tried to work around the same but was not succesful. This dont even open six instances of command prompt, and the delete command appended to the first commmand from text file and throws an error

Comment: Hey Aacini, Thanks for your effort. But the command dosent work. When I ran this command I got error for Start "" "call %%x ^& del cmdInstance!nextInstance!.txt". I tried to work around the same but was not succesful. This dont even open six instances of command prompt, and the delete commandgets appended to the first commmand from text file and throws an error.cannot find command.

Comment: Oops! There was a small bug... Fixed, try it again!

Comment: Great Aacini. It actually worked.This batch now does open six command prompt which runs the different commands. there is one bug though it also opens one more command prompt with all the commands. dont know what that is. Again I didnt get the time to validate whether after the first command get completed whether the next in text file gets executed or not, because each command takes 20 mins to execute and am already late.I will go home and try to set up on my system locally and then may be try to reply back over night with results..A thumbs up for you!!Thanks will keep you posted..Great job!!.

Comment: @Aacini..I tested the batch and yes it does execute the commands on six command prompts and as soon. As one of the command gets executed new command prompt opens and execute the next command. One issue though sometime it opens 7 command prompts. But I guess I can go with that. I have one issue though. Am not able to get the start time and end time of the entire execution. Means when all the command gets executed I wanted to know when the first command started and the last command ended so that I can keep track of time required to execute 100 commands.

Comment: Reposted the code which is working for me. Also I was thinking to bring in more complexity. Suppose if I want an incremental command execution. i.e first it should run only one command in one command window,as soon as it gets over then it should run the next two commands in two command window, as soon as this gets completed it should start three command prompt with three commands executing at the same time at till all the 100 commands gets executed with start and end time for entire execution. I guess it is a lot more complex and intereting. Can you help me with this Aacini.Thanks In Advance..

Comment: I have modified the batch file and now it outputs the commands with their start time in a log file. now the issue am facing is, I am not able to figure out how can I get the end time printed to the log after all the command have finished execution. Plus I also want to modify this code for incrimental command prompt execution. i.e for 1 command execution on 1 command window as soon as it get over with execution then next two command execution on two command windows then after execution three commands on three command window.Please help...

Comment: Ok. Got it how to do it in incremental way. I have planned this approach. I will create a batch file inside that batch file I will make call to other batch files. Since I have to run 100 commands in an incremental manner I will call each batch file in the below order.Batch1(Executing 1 command), Batch2(Executing 2 commands ), Batch3(Executing 3 commands),Batch4(Executing 4 commands) and so on till Batch13. At the same time printing the time required to execute each batch to a log file. I will also have to make sure is that the next batch does not start before the completion of the first.

Comment: Finished with creating incremental batch.The commands available here with me are not time consuming so cannot really see the actual behaviour will have to wait till monday to implement this in office.So far I created 13 batch files as I explained before and was able to call it from a master file. Now the only thing remains is writing the end time after the last command gets executed. Can someone help me to output the time at the end of entire execution in the above code by Aacini. If anyone can help me with this than I can go ahead and modify the logic which I created for iterative cmd executn

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini for your expert help. You are clearly the expert. I created 13 batch files and 1 master file to call those 13 incrementally and you achieved the same with a single batch file. My approach is a bit time consuming wherein you have to update the path in all the 13 files once the file is taken to a different system. to add to it I was also able to create op file for each execution of command giving the start and end time of each command. Is there any way by which I can output the execution on each cmd window to a single file.Thanks a ton!!!!!! for your Expert help.